# Using BouncyCastle with GnuPG 2.1's `pubring.kbx` file

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg, openpgp

I'm trying to use BouncyCastle with PGP2 to read public keys ring. The problem is that since GnuPG 2.1 it's stored in `pubring.kbx` instead of `pubring.gpg`. That leads to IOException `public key ring doesn't start with public key tag: tag 0x0`

Any idea if and how I can use BC with GnuPG 2.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GnuPG 2.1 by default uses the new keybox file format](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#sec-1-11) -- if no `pubring.gpg` is found. If there is a "legacy" keyring file, it will be used instead.

I'm not aware Bouncy Castle supports the `.kbx` file format. So if you want to use Bouncy Castle together on the same key files GnuPG is using, you've got three options:

- Additionally maintaining an old `pubring.gpg` file somewhere else, which means running an `gpg --export` or `--export-secret-keys` when needed. The old `pubring.gpg` is just a dump of keys, you can directly use the export output as keyring.
- Using a `pubring.gpg` in your GnuPG home directory, with other words dropping the better performance of the `.kbx` file in exchange for compatiblity.

  First of all, be sure to copy the whole `~/.gnupg` folder or make sure to have an up-to-date backup!

  In the end, the migration process boils down to exporting the information in the keybox file to the old OpenPGP keyring format. Looking at the proposal for migration from `.kbx` files to `.gpg` files from the changelog linked above:

  ```
  $ cd ~/.gnupg
  $ gpg --export-ownertrust > otrust.lst
  $ mv pubring.gpg publickeys
  $ gpg2 --import-options import-local-sigs --import publickeys
  $ gpg2 --import-ownertrust otrust.lst
  ```

  The reverse process should look rather similar (given no secret keys are stored, otherwise read below, and exchange `gpg2` and `gpg` to match the binaries installed on your machine):

  ```
  $ cd ~/.gnupg
  $ gpg2 --export-ownertrust > otrust.lst
  $ gpg2 --export > pubring.gpg
  $ mv pubring.kbx pubring.kbx~
  $ gpg2 --import-options import-local-sigs
  $ gpg2 --import-ownertrust otrust.lst
  ```

  The `--export` result can directly be used as new keyring, so no `--import` of this file is needed. Ownertrust should probably be copied in a similar manner, I just kept was the changelog proposed here.

  If you've also stored private keys, I'd better export them first into another file and finally importing them again:

  ```
  $ cd ~/.gnupg
  $ gpg2 --export-secret-keys > secret-keys.gpg
  $ gpg2 --export-ownertrust > otrust.lst
  $ gpg2 --export > pubring.gpg
  $ mv pubring.kbx pubring.kbx~
  $ gpg2 --import-options import-local-sigs --import secret-keys.gpg
  $ gpg2 --import-ownertrust otrust.lst
  ```
- Implement the `.kbx` format for Bouncy Castle.

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.60 BouncyCastle support reading KeyBox files.

https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html

> A parser has now been added for the GNU keybox file format. The GPG SExpr parser now covers a wider range of key types.

There is some example code in [KeyBoxTest.java](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/gpg/test/KeyBoxTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

If you have come here then you will realize that the API leap from .pgp to .kbx files in bouncycastle is poorly documented.  I've looked at alternatives such as https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless and org.eclipse.jgit.gpg.bc which attempt to rationalize the changes. But refactoring existing code which uses .pgp keyring files over to .kbx is extremely challenging.