# bouncy castle open gpg2 public key

Tags: java, kotlin, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp

I tried to implement the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216302/4727842. My code looks like this

```
private fun readPublicKey(input: InputStream): PGPPublicKey {
    val publicKey = PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(input), BcKeyFingerprintCalculator())
    var key: PGPPublicKey? = null

    publicKey.keyRings.forEach { ring: PGPPublicKeyRing ->
        ring.publicKeys.forEach { k: PGPPublicKey ->
            if (k.isEncryptionKey) {
                key = k
            }
        }
    }

    if (key == null) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't find encryption key input key ring.")
    } else {
        return key!!
    }
}

private fun encrypt(file: File): String {
    val input = IOUtils.toInputStream("pub.asc", "UTF-8")
    val key = readPublicKey(input)

    Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())

    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val compressor = PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP)

    PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(compressor.open(out), PGPLiteralData.BINARY, file)
    compressor.close()

    val builder = BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES)
    val generator = PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(builder.setSecureRandom(SecureRandom()))

    generator.addMethod(BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(key))

    return String(out.toByteArray())
}
```

Using the gpg cli (v2.2.15), after generating a key, I output the asc file.

`gpg -ab -o ./pub.asc`

its contents look like this

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQEzBAABCAAdFiEEpjyVE0VY1bLTdOo7wzVyPJ8SXFIFAlzbRfQACgkQwzVyPJ8S
XFKtjwgAp1ad9jFxKtsbzR4XT4HqypTPxpwY8raoIeXNg2PMDAFXGqmcRmP4NEBO
BYqalHAxrzXKVPcmKHtYnm7Jb91VLcYycsF+9RM53mwhg2YJhv49xROx8IsJuhVG
8X52nhPc+qQtzE/79FPDgiZNKSnrHUDvPU3rrZH44WPsGQJ9iGy0eoJPomuU29Cb
wWYxOHq8fRmL5h5Pi9mU1dJRZvHej8ewt0DpredY//7Er7xjCKHrFyzddSn1sGtv
QvoOP+1pLNCV/LKAgCz2N2vSOToLqYTuQlrO/kNApnza0+lO0GW4RMf0OJntbSIa
MHDa+/uc9YnyABkptxD2a9DsbvHwvg==
=QeFf
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Then with the line

`val input = IOUtils.toInputStream("pub.asc", "UTF-8")`

I attempted to run. It output the message `"Can't find encryption key input key ring."` after failing to extract a key. After debugging I saw that `publicKey.keyRings` size was `0`.

I didn't understand the situation since the linked guide seems to advocate using the `.asc` file for encrypting when I thought it was for signing. I don't know much about PGP but I thought those were different steps and that maybe signing was not necessary for my use case.

So, I tried exporting the public key

`gpg --export -a "User" > public.key`

containing

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=
=9i+0
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

and ran with

`val input = IOUtils.toInputStream("public.key", "UTF-8")`

This yielded no change. bouncycastle found no keys in my public key file. I then saw that since I am using gpg2 there are differences in how key rings are handled. I found a solution to convert a `.pkr` to a `.kbx` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221494/4727842 but at this point this has become woefully complicated. I don't know the difference between a public key ring and a public key. I don't know why the first example used a `.asc` file as a suposedly valid keyring. I especially don't know why it is so hard to create a bouncycastle `PGPPublicKey` object from my `public.key` file.

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is your question?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I am trying to encrypt files with pgp. I am unable to provide a public key that bouncy castle will accept as outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do proper en-/decryption use [bouncy-gpg](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg) (shameless plug: I am the author).

Also do not use 3DES, it is dead Slow and not the most modern algorithm (though it is still considered secure, AFAIK).

You export the public key via `gpg --export -a me@example.com`.

You manage keys using the `InMemoryKeyring` (see [here](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg/blob/master/README.md#recommendation-inmemorykeyring) for details):

```java
public static KeyringConfig keyringConfigInMemoryForKeys(final String exportedPubKey, final String exportedPrivateKey, final String passphrase) throws IOException, PGPException {

   final InMemoryKeyring keyring = KeyringConfigs.forGpgExportedKeys(KeyringConfigCallbacks.withPassword(passphrase);

       keyring.addPublicKey(exportedPubKey.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
// you can add many more public keys

       // if you only want to encrypt you do not need a private key and can ignore this line
keyring.addSecretKey(exportedPrivateKey.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
// you can add many more private keys

return keyring;
}


final String original_message = "I love deadlines. I like the whooshing sound they make as they fly by. Douglas Adams";

// Most likely you will use  one of the KeyringConfigs.... methods.
KeyringConfig keyringConfigOfSender = keyringConfigInMemoryForKeys(..); // TODO - here comes your code to get keys

ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(result);

    final OutputStream outputStream = BouncyGPG
        .encryptToStream()
        .withConfig(keyringConfigOfSender)
        .withStrongAlgorithms()
        .toRecipients("recipient@example.com", "sender@example.com") // TODO - also your job to set the recipients 
        .andSignWith("sender@example.com") // TODO - same here
        .binaryOutput()
        .andWriteTo(bufferedOutputStream);
    // Maybe read a file or a webservice?
    final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(original_message.getBytes())
) {
  Streams.pipeAll(is, outputStream);
// It is very important that outputStream is closed before the result stream is read.
// The reason is that GPG writes the signature at the end of the stream.
// This is triggered by closing the stream.
// In this example outputStream is closed via the try-with-resources mechanism of Java
}

result.close();
byte[] chipertext = result.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PGPainless](https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless) for that (another shameless plug - Author here as well :P):

```java
        // Prepare keys
        // Required by the sender
        PGPSecretKeyRing keyAlice = PGPainless.readKeyRing().secretKeyRing(ALICE_KEY);
        PGPPublicKeyRing certificateBob = PGPainless.readKeyRing().publicKeyRing(BOB_CERT);
        SecretKeyRingProtector protectorAlice = SecretKeyRingProtector.unprotectedKeys();

        // Required by the recipient
        PGPSecretKeyRing keyBob = PGPainless.readKeyRing().secretKeyRing(BOB_KEY);
        PGPPublicKeyRing certificateAlice = PGPainless.readKeyRing().publicKeyRing(ALICE_CERT);
        SecretKeyRingProtector protectorBob = SecretKeyRingProtector.unprotectedKeys();

        // plaintext message to encrypt
        String message = "Hello, World!\n";
        ByteArrayOutputStream ciphertext = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Encrypt and sign
        EncryptionStream encryptor = PGPainless.encryptAndOrSign()
                .onOutputStream(ciphertext)
                .withOptions(ProducerOptions.signAndEncrypt(
                        // we want to encrypt communication (affects key selection based on key flags)
                        EncryptionOptions.encryptCommunications()
                                .addRecipient(certificateBob)
                                .addRecipient(certificateAlice),
                        new SigningOptions()
                                .addInlineSignature(protectorAlice, keyAlice, DocumentSignatureType.CANONICAL_TEXT_DOCUMENT)
                        ).setAsciiArmor(true)
                );

        // Pipe data trough and CLOSE the stream (important)
        Streams.pipeAll(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), encryptor);
        encryptor.close();

        // Encrypted message
        String encryptedMessage = ciphertext.toString();

        // Decrypt and verify signatures
        DecryptionStream decryptor = PGPainless.decryptAndOrVerify()
                .onInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .withOptions(new ConsumerOptions()
                        .addDecryptionKey(keyBob, protectorBob)
                        .addVerificationCert(certificateAlice)
                );

        ByteArrayOutputStream plaintext = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Streams.pipeAll(decryptor, plaintext);
        decryptor.close();

        // Check the metadata to see how the message was encrypted/signed
        OpenPgpMetadata metadata = decryptor.getResult();
        assertTrue(metadata.isEncrypted());
        assertTrue(metadata.containsVerifiedSignatureFrom(certificateAlice));
        assertEquals(message, plaintext.toString());
```

And if you want it even simpler, PGPainless provides a SOP (Stateless OpenPGP Protocol) API via [pgpainless-sop](https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless/tree/master/pgpainless-sop):

```java
SOP sop = new SOPImpl();
        
// Generate an OpenPGP key - Alternatively just read existing (unencrypted) key from disk
byte[] key = sop.generateKey()
        .userId("Alice <alice@example.org>")
        .generate()
        .getBytes();

// Extract the certificate (public key) - alternatively just read certificate from disk
byte[] cert = sop.extractCert()
        .key(key)
        .getBytes();

// Encrypt a message
byte[] message = ...
byte[] encrypted = sop.encrypt()
        .withCert(cert)
        .signWith(key)
        .plaintext(message)
        .getBytes();

// Decrypt a message
ByteArrayAndResult<DecryptionResult> messageAndVerifications = sop.decrypt()
        .verifyWith(cert)
        .withKey(key)
        .ciphertext(encrypted)
        .toByteArrayAndResult();
byte[] decrypted = messageAndVerifications.getBytes();
// Signature Verifications
DecryptionResult messageInfo = messageAndVerifications.getResult();
List<Verification> signatureVerifications = messageInfo.getVerifications();
```